# How much pressure can mountain bike tires take?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, tire-pressure

I am thinking of buying a new mountain bike, but I'm unfamiliar with mountain bikes. That's why I need to be well aware of the pressure a mountain bike can handle. How much pressure can mountain bike tires take?

Comment: Not sure what you are attempting to ask - is it about tire pressure?

Comment: Is this about tyre pressure or how versatile/bombproof mountain bikes are?

Comment: The maximum pressure is generally stamped onto the sidewall of a tyre. It will be specific to the tyre, as opposed to the bike or the genre of bike. Does this help you? Its difficult to work out what you're asking.

Comment: Normally bike tires will have a max pressure rating (shown on the sidewall) higher than you'd want to use, except maybe on smooth pavement (where higher pressures are especially useful).  Generally for off-road use you will want a pressure somewhat lower than the max (though not so low that the tire "bottoms out" and results in "snakebite" punctures).

Comment: The maximum pressure stamped on the sidewall of MTB tire is almost complete garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Says on the sidewall of a tyre. Mine says between 40-60psi. They also have it in 'bars' if you like to measure in that.

Check out an example here 
http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/schwalbe-magic-mary-evo-mtb-tyre-super-gravity/rp-prod118255

Says max 50psi.

Answer (score 3):

Most bike mechanics will tell you that the best performance is not attained at maximum tyre pressure.

My own tyres take up to 4.5 bar, yet the best ride is at around 2.5 bar.

For whatever reason, my bike rolls better in the terrrain at 2.5 bar than at 3 bar.